# How do I know which registry an image was pulled from in Docker?

Tags: docker

In Docker I am running a DockerFile set up as follows:

```
# Comment
FROM python:3.8.3

RUN pip install matplotlib
```

I am generating this image with the following command:

`docker build -t myimage:mytag -f DockerFile .`

Here's my understanding of what this does:

- `python:3.8.3` image is "pulled" from some remote registry
- A new "layer" is built on top of this base image and tagged as `myimage:mytag`
- matplotlib is installed in this new layer

My question is this: is there any way to (programmatically) determine which registry the base image is pulled from?

Comment: Do you mean the exact server of Docker Hub or what?

Comment: An `image:version` combination is supposed to be unique, it shouldn't matter which registry it was retrieved from, or something is seriously wrong with your setup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Registry:
You can find your `default` registry with the following command:

```
# docker info | grep -i registry
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
```

It shows you where docker searches if you do not specify another registry.

**Example**: Pull python:3.8.3 from the "default" Registry index.docker.io/v1/

```
# docker pull python:3.8.3
3.8.3: Pulling from library/python
...
...
...
Status: Downloaded newer image for python:3.8.3
docker.io/library/python:3.8.3
```

Verfiy the Image (you will see, there is no suffix to the ImageID):

```
# docker images | grep -i python
python                               3.8.3               7f5b6ccd03e9        6 weeks ago         934MB
```

**Example**: Pull Image `nginx` from the `fedora registry`:

```
# docker pull registry.fedoraproject.org/f29/nginx
Using default tag: latest
latest: Pulling from f29/nginx
...
Status: Downloaded newer image for registry.fedoraproject.org/f29/nginx:latest
registry.fedoraproject.org/f29/nginx:latest
```

Verify the Image (you will see, there is now a suffix to the ImageID):

```
# docker images | grep -i nginx
registry.fedoraproject.org/f29/nginx   latest              225d690974f7        20 months ago       368MB
```